# Is there any other way to store values in DB other than 'system_settings_form'?

Tags: 7

On change(using AJAX) of Job title the text area will show and admin will enter text in admin form. By using `system_settings_form` I am storing values in DB using Variables.

**PROBLEM:**

1. I have more than 20 values in the dropdown.
2. For this I need to store the textarea values in a variable.
3. This leads to huge values stored in `variable` table.

Is there any other way rather than using this, or is this the best way of using?

***I am just checking all the possibilities.***

Any Ideas will be much appreciated, Thanks.

[image]

Comment: You can use your own submit function, and store the values in a custom table. But is there some reason for this? What are your concerns?

Comment: Yeh i agree to use custom table. But jus for storing few values I would suggest to go with variable it self. So, I thought of is there something beyond this.

Comment: @Nagarjuna: All you really have is the database so its pretty much either a custom table or the variables table. It's up to you which option you deem appropriate in which situation. You can also store a serialized array in a single variable if you use a custom submit handler.

Comment: There are 3 options. 1) Creating new entity 2) Working with ctools export api 3) Custom table with your own read write helper function.

Answer (score 1):

You can store your data wherever you like, in whatever format you like, and you can manage it in any way that php allows; Drupal doesn't have an opinion on the matter.

If you're asking whether Drupal has another variable API you can use for this slightly different requirement, then no it doesn't.

So to answer your question directly

> Is there any other way to store values in DB other than 'system_settings_form'

Yes, just use the [database API](https://www.drupal.org/developing/api/database) in whatever way you think is appropriate for the data you're storing/retrieving. Various modules provide data layers, e.g. ctools has a data API as Jimmy mentioned in the comments. There's also the core entity API, but that's going to be overkill for your needs.

All that said, you might want to actually profile your code to see if 20 values serialised into a single row is going to cause you any real problems. Yours and MySQL's definition of "huge" might be quite different.